# git cherry-pick and merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-cherry-pick

My current branch is branch-X. I cherry-pick a commit Y from branch-Z and later plan to merge branch-Y into branch-X. Will commit Y be applied again during the merge?

Matthias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, git is clever enough that when you merge branches it does not re-apply patches that founds are already applied.

You can try that with rebasing the branch with the commit from where you cherry-picked it (your branch-Z) into the branch you cherry-picked it (branch-X).

Answer (score 0):

No, as long as the commit is unchanged git will detect that it is already applied and skip it. If the commit has changed in one of the branches you may get a conflict which is resolved in the same manner as with other conflicts.